# Google Custom Search API issue: up to 100 queries

Tags: iphone, google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I want to use Google Custom Search API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview to search images by keywords.

At [main page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) they say:
**Usage is free for all users, up to 100 queries per day.** Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day.

**What do they mean:** Is that the limit for all users of my application? or each of my users can make up to 100 queries? If you don't know the answer, may be you know the url of google help for these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are supposed to get API key for this service, most likely Google calculates queries number based on your API key, so you get 100 free queries each day in total per single API key (which would be the same for all of your users), and not 100 queries for each user.

Answer (score -1):

Google needs to clarify this.

I enabled billing and I'm not getting squat.

First of all, with billing enabled, paid subscription, it is not possible to do a Google Custom Search (api), and process more than 100 results from that search.  If you have access to more than 100 results (with 1K++ or a million results returned), prove it, send me the code.

---

Also those 100 results? right so that consumes 10 searches.  You do the initial search (that's 1 search consumed), you get back 10 results in the JSON response, and you want the next 10? Great, you have to do/consume another search against the quota using &start=11 to get the next ten, and so on, up to 100 (consuming 10 searches), and then you get `404` when `&start=101`.

This is yet another **BIG GOOGLE FAIL!**.